# How to create a DateTime column From Date and Hour column in Power Query

Tags: datetime, powerquery

I have this column in a table:

2019-10-01 01
2019-10-01 02
2019-10-01 03...

How can I use Power Query to convert it (or create a new column) into a proper DateTime column, where "01,02,03" values above are the hours?  I'm dealing in dates and hours only.

Power Query will not recognize it natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you append `":00"` to the end of the column, it should be able to interpret it as a DateTime format.

```
Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"Col", each DateTime.FromText(_&":00"), type datetime}})
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexis!  I used a variation on your theme:
= Table.AddColumn(#"PreviousStep", "DateTime", each [Date] & ":00")
Since I was working with hour-ending times, I had to also replace hour 24:00 with 00:00.  Then it recognized it as a valid Date/Time.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following input table

[image]

This worked for me

```
let
    source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    splitByDelimiter = Table.SplitColumn(source, "Input", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Date", "Time"}),
    changedType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(splitByDelimiter,{{"Date", type date}, {"Time", type time}})
in
    changedType
```

with the following result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have your column named Column1, like this:

[image]

You can use this code:

```
Table.TransformColumns(Source,{"Column1", each #datetime(Number.From(Text.Range(_,0,4)),Number.From(Text.Range(_,5,2)),Number.From(Text.Range(_,8,2)),Number.From(Text.Range(_,11,2)),0,0)})
```

To get this:

[image]

Just copy the code above, click on the [image], and paste the code in the formula bar. If your column is not named Column1, replace the reference to Column1 with the name of your column.